# Delegate methods objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I think that I understand how delegate pattern work, but that part is not clear for me.

How to create custom delegate method which returns a result ?
Where returned value goes ?
How to use dataSource with delegate methods

Here is what I mean. That is a delegate method of UITableViewDelegate. Depending of returned value table row have different height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 22;
}
```

I read apple documentation about the topic but I'm still confused.

Please, provide me some simple code examples if possible.

Comment: the table view has a reference to its delegate, so the tv asks its delegate for the height value.. the value is used by the tv, which resize rows accordingly. dataSource & delegate are different in the sense that they play a different role, but the mecanism is the same for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good and thorough explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11) and [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/81489-how-why-implement-delegation-pattern.html) you can see example code and some more information about the Delegate pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Delegation is one example of what's called a **design pattern**. Here's [Apple documentation on delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

On iOS, the UIApplication class provides a nice example of delegation. The UIApplicationDelegate protocol specifies this (optional) method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

The class that serves as the delegate for the UIApplication can implement this method, and this method will execute when the application is about to terminate. Therefore, delegation is a technique that allows for customized behavior in off-the-shelf objects (UIApplication in this case). Applications have to terminate all the time, but it's up to the programmer(s) of each app to decide what needs to happen just before the app terminates.

Apple's documentation states:

> You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for your application, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, invalidating timers, and storing enough application state to reconstitute your application’s interface when it is relaunched. Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.