# Passing data between two containers in a same viewcontroller

Tags: ios6, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new to iOS programming, I read a lot of tutorials and forums but I still can't figure the best way to manage a project.

What I want is the iPad screen to display a CollectionView and a TableView side by side.
Actions in the CollectionView should change TableView content. SplitViewController won't do the job because of the fixed size of the split.

For now I'm using Storyboard, I created a ViewController and added two ContainerViews in it. Each container is linked by an XCode generated segue to a view controller (LeftViewController and RightViewController).

I'm trying to figure the smartest way to manage actions on the LeftViewController and send changes to the RightViewController.

I would like to use Storyboard that seems more elegant, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You want to make the primary viewController a delegate of the two controllers in the containers, and pass information between them.  If you need code samples, I will provide some.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the kind of answer I was waiting for. Code samples are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the way to establish delegate methods (@protocol, see [here for links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393193/542400)), the key elements will be grabbing the two viewControllers embedded in containers as they are being loaded, setting the primary viewController as delegate, and sending the messages when something changes.  For starters, if communication needs to flow both ways between controllers, set up an instance variable for each VC.

Given VCPrime, CollectionVC, and TableVC:

First, in storyboards, name each of your segues (from the containerViews to the VCs).  In VCPrime, implement prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"collection"]) {
        self.collectionVC = (CollectionVC *)[segue destinationViewController];
        self.collectionVC.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"table"]) {
        self.tableVC = (TableVC *)[segue destinationViewController];
        self.tableVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

You must also implement the delegate methods in VCPrime, and declare `CollectionDelegate, TableDelegate`, or however you named them.

In CollectionVC, when someone selects something (or whatever), check that the delegate responds to your delegate method, then send that message:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) [self.delegate doSomething];
```

Then alter TableVC in the method that is called.

This is just a quick rundown.  The internets are alive with great code examples.

Comment: Thank you ! Using delegates works fine. I thought segues were only used for transitions between full screen pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have an improvement in Swift (the answer is old but I was facing this problem a day ago).  I re-implemented the above in Swift, but with a twist.  Instead of setting the VCPrime as a delegate for for both CollectionVC and TableVC, I would make the TableVC a delegate of CollectionVC.  That is because CollectionVC needs to control TableVC.  In general we can call a "master VC" the one that controls and the "delegate VC" the one that is controlled. In order to make sure that both VC are actually instantiated when I set one as the delegate of the other, I use Swift optionals and optional bindings.  Here is a sample of code" (note that the master needs to have a "delegate" property and you might want to declare the appropriate protocols):

```
import UIKit

class ContainerController: UIViewController {

    private var masterViewController: myMasterViewController?
    private var delegateViewController: myDelegateViewController?

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "myMasterViewController" {
            masterViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? myMasterViewController
        } else if segue.identifier == "myDelegateViewController" {
            delegateViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? myDelegateViewController
        }
        if let master = masterViewController, delegate = delegateViewController {
            println("Master and delegate set")
            master.delegate = delegate
        }
    }
}
```